# How do I center an image gallery in CSS?

Tags: html, css, center

I've created an image gallery but I am unsure about how to center the images in the middle of the page horizontally and vertically.

```
 <div class="gallery">
     <a target="_blank" href="Icon_pyro.jpg">
      <img src="Icon_pyro.jpg" alt="Pyro" width="256" height="256">
     </a>
   <div class="desc">Pyro</div>
 </div>
```

With my CSS classes being

```
div.gallery {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  div.gallery img {
    margin: 5px;

  }
```

It shows up stacked on top, I am stumped on how to make them side by side

[Current webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pjd9.png)

Comment: you can add a css language identifer to highlight the code and make it better to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` property to fix your problem.

I will give you some Idea........................

### *horizontally center*

if you use `display:flex;` all `div` elements are show as row. Then if you use `justify-content:center;` you row element will be center horizontally.

**.html**

```
<div class="imageContainer">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/256x256">
  </div>
  
  <div class="img">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/256x256">
  </div>
  
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/256x256">
  </div>
</div>
```

**.css**

```
.imageContainer{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.img{
  margin:5px;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/hme9ynof/8/)

### *Vertically center*

You have to only add `align-items: center;` and `min-height: 100vh;`

```
  .imageContainer{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
   }
```

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/Lh2d048f/9/)

### *horizontally and vertically Center.*

just add (here has both above css propertise. have a look and get the idea)

```
.imageContainer{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
   min-height:100vh;
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/wx0g2dp9/)

As well as check following example it will show you how to center columns items vertically and horizontally (just added `flex-direction:column;`)

```
.imageContainer{
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   min-height:100vh;
   flex-direction:column;
   justify-content:center;
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/wx0g2dp9/8/)

[Here is the tutorial if you want to follow and get some idea about flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you will want to wrap the images using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to get them side by side.

In that case, I would create a `gallery-wrapper` div that wraps around all of your `gallery` divs. You can style the `gallery-wrapper` to get `flex`, which will make it's children side-by-side by default. Also, add `justify-content: center`, to center things horizontally. Check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdu4byzt/1/) / my updated answer, and consider learning more about [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) styling - it's the best.

```css
.gallery-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="Icon_pyro.jpg">
      <img src="Icon_pyro.jpg" alt="Pyro" width="256" height="256">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Pyro</div>
  </div>
          
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="Icon_scout.jpg">
      <img src="Icon_scout.jpg" alt="Scout" width="256" height="256">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Scout</div>
  </div>
          
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="Icon_spy.jpg">
      <img src="Icon_spy.jpg" alt="Spy" width="256" height="256">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Spy</div>
  </div>
          
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="Icon_soldier.jpg">
      <img src="Icon_soldier.jpg" alt="Soldier" width="256" height="256">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Soldier</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Apologies, here is the full outline of all four photos I had intially tried to do. I am aiming to make all these photos side by side. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/L0sgS66Z)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

You have to add one parent element for all the `gallery` elements and give flex utility property to that parent. You need to set the height of gallery parent element as per requirements (currently, we have set viewport height for the below demo).

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/b2fq8dhr/